# How I find empty Solr document fields with lucene query

Tags: solr, lucene

i have some documents like this:

```
<doc>
  <str name="navTitle"/>
  <str name="title">Word 1</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="navTitle">Word 2</str>
  <str name="title">Word 3</str>
</doc>
```

and i will find all documents with an emtpy "navTitle" field! 
How is the lucene query for this?

I trying " navTitle:'' " and I trying " navTitle:' ' ", but the Solr Admin Panal find nothing.
Whats wrong at the query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [SolrQuerySytax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) page they says that you can use the following query to find all empty queries.

```
-field:[* TO *] finds all documents without a value for field
```

Comment: Thanks, that is it. I ignored the "-" Operator